# If $z \in \mathbb{C}$, is it true that $\frac{\left|z\right|^n}{\left|z\right|^{2n}-1} < \ldots$

Tags: complex-analysis

> $\frac{\left|z\right|^n}{\left|z\right|^{2n}-1} <\frac{\left|z\right|^n-1}{(\left|z\right|^n-1)(\left|z\right|^n+1)}$

I am working through a proof that has this inequality. If I'm not mistake, this must be a typo. Can others opine?

Comment: $n=1$ and $z=2$ ?

Comment: It's true if $\lvert z\rvert < 1$, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, 
$$
\frac{a}{b}>\frac{a-1}{b}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for confirming my thinking.